Is it true that with the use of C++ modules your modules/translation units cannot be built in parallel anymore?
In the CMake documentation it says that using modules means that the build process is no longer quote "embarrassingly parallel". I think the build system has to sort which modules can be compiled first. On the other hand translation units can all be built in parallel. Does this mean that using modules will be a slower build because of this?

Remember that the point of modules was to reduce eliminate time spent parsing common headers for every TU.

Having multiple translation units means that build is already quite slow and modules may only work as an alternative for precompiled header. In theory they should offer faster build compared to precompiled header because they don't expose every symbol. However they require a complex build setup and some code changes as a trade-off while precompiled header can be used with simpler build setup and without code changes. Modules could've been great for third-party deps, however standard didn't define format of module files and makes you build them yourself rendering modules rather useless.

*"Does this mean that using modules will be a slower build because of this?"*Some are slower, some are faster. There is an additional serial part, a dependency graph, but parallel part of each TU should be shorter.

I covered this, although it’s hard to call it a duplicate based on just that.
